# Is Magic Trackpad feature-equivalent with built-in MacBook touchpads/trackpads?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, trackpad, magic-trackpad

**TLDR**; for testing touchpad interface on a MacBook, would a desktop with Magic Trackpad be suitable?

---

We are developing a cross-platform application Win/Mac and though we develop mostly on Windows, MacBook users are a key demographic, specifically this raises issues with trackpad functionality.
None of us have MacBooks but I have a MacMini so I can test the Mac build - but only with a mouse. I wondered if getting a TrackPad would let me test gestures a)work as planned b)are user friendly in a realistic way. If so, which version would be adequate?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Magic Trackpad or Magic Trackpad 2 should allow you to test gestures and work out if they're user friendly.

The only problem I can see is if you have very odd gestures or use of the track pad that relies on the specific physical size of the trackpad (which is normally not the case). The size of the trackpad varies from Mac to Mac (i.e. older models typically have smaller trackpads).

Comment: Sure... We're after fairly generic gestures and it's mainly making sure they work in a friendly way when none of us use anything except a mouse!